# transponer y copiar columnas de datos de un registro a filas en otra hoja y luego limpiar la hoja de origen google sheet macro

Tags: javascript

Tengo una hoja de registro con columnas que cada día se llena con datos,necesito copiar estos datos de las columnas a otra hoja en filas y que se vayan agregando según la fecha, una vez copiado que en la hoja de registro se limpien los datos para el siguiente registro. He intentado con una macro, no soy un experto, por eso recurro a su ayuda[image: Modulo 1]

Modulo 2[image: ][1]]

Comment: Creo que deberías explicar mejor tu problema. Entendí que estás utilizando **Google Sheets**? Y quieres hacer una macro o un procedimiento? Para transponer los valores puedes utilizar la función **TRANSPONER**. Igualmente te sugiero revisar [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta se entienda mejor.

Comment: Asi es en en google sheets,En la primera hoja registro datos en columnas  que necesito se copien a otra hoja en filas modulo 2, en la ultima fila de lo copiado el dia anterior.posteriormente limpiar el registro para su llenado el dia siguiente.lo que necesito es una macro para ejecutarlo ,es mi primera pregunta por favor entienda que siempre se tiene errores

Comment: Y solucionaste tu problema? @genaro-davila

Comment: la verdad que no, lo he intentado con esta macro                     function Transponer() {      var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1l0E3r1hiW8fxvPRVQugsW2XXvNpFF9cj07huSgaC5zU");
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("modulo 1");
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName("Modulo 2");
  var RangetoCopy=sh.getRange('C5:F128'); 
  var DestRange=dsh.getRange(dsh.getLastRow()+1,1);
  RangetoCopy.copyTo(DestRange ,{contentsOnly: true});   
  };

Comment: he utilizado este macro pero me lo copia en el modulo 2 de forma vertical y no como estoy necesitando